# Using custom tasks to build android modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My project on Android Studio has multiple modules(MyApp1,MyApp2 etc.) and i want to create a custom task so that instead of calling `./gradlew :MyApp1:assembleDebug:` , i want to call something like `./gradlew releaseMyApp1`.

I want to customize that task, so it will clean the projects first, and then edit the sub project's build informations (version name,version number etc.).

First i want to ask if i can i can put all those custom tasks inside the root projects `build.gradle` file? Secondly how can i call the subproject `assembleDebug` or `assembleRelease` tasks from another gradle script? I tried something like this(inside root project `build.gradle` but it doesnt do anything for me:

```
task releaseMyApp1{
finalizedBy ':MyApp1:assembleDebug'
// clean the projects, change version name, number etc
}
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`task releaseMyApp1(dependsOn: ':MyApp1:assembleDebug')`

Comment: But this task calls `:MyApp1:assembleDebug` first and then executes `releaseMyApp1`, doesn't it? I want to do  it the other way around. I want to do some things before  `:MyApp1:assembleDebug` is called.

Comment: I did exactly as you asked: `i want to create a custom task so that instead of calling ./gradlew :MyApp1:assembleDebug: , i want to call something like ./gradlew releaseMyApp1`.